The double parameter is not updated in the display when it is changed in the MVVM command in NET MAUI
I am making a client application for a product store. The shopping cart is located on the server and the data is transferred there using requests to the server. The product basket is an ObservableCollection. The view also shows the total price generated in the ViewModel constructor. I implemented the command to remove an item from the observablecollection, and also put in the command to subtract the cost of the deleted item from the total amount parameter. The deleted item disappears from the list in the view, but the displayed amount remains the same.
XAML Code:
<StackLayout>
    
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsInBasket}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="clv_basket">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  x:DataType="dataModel:DTOProductAndQuantity">
                <Frame Padding="2" Margin="25,10,25,0" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" CornerRadius="15">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Frame Grid.Column="0" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="15" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="{Binding product.Photo, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToImage}}"/>
                        </Frame>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding product.NameProduct}" FontSize="19" TextColor="#006064" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding product.Category}" FontSize="18" TextColor="#006064" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding product.Cost, StringFormat='cost per piece: {0} rub.'}" FontSize="18" TextColor="#006064" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
                                <Label Text="{Binding quantityInBusket}" FontSize="17" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="BlueViolet"/>
                                <Stepper Maximum="10"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Increment="1" Value="{Binding quantityInBusket}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Button VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteProductCommand, Source={x:Reference clv_basket}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Frame CornerRadius="2">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Sum, StringFormat='Sum: {0} rub.'}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>

ViewModel Code:
class BusketViewModel
{
    #region Fields
    private double sum;
    private ObservableCollection<DTOProductAndQuantity> productsInBasket;
    private ObservableCollection<DTOProductAndQuantity> productsFromHttp;
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    private Command<object> deleteProductCommand;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public BusketViewModel()
    {
        productsFromHttp = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ObservableCollection<DTOProductAndQuantity>>("http://10.0.2.2:5125/api/Busket").Result;
        deleteProductCommand = new Command<object>(DeleteProduct);


        ProductsInBasket = new ObservableCollection<DTOProductAndQuantity>(productsFromHttp);
        foreach (var i in ProductsInBasket)            
            Sum += i.product.Cost * i.quantityInBusket;


    }
    
    private void DeleteProduct(object obj)
    {            
        Sum -= (obj as DTOProductAndQuantity).product.Cost * (obj as DTOProductAndQuantity).quantityInBusket;
        ProductsInBasket.Remove(obj as  DTOProductAndQuantity);
        
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public ObservableCollection<DTOProductAndQuantity> ProductsInBasket
    {
        get { return productsInBasket; }
        set
        {
            if (productsInBasket != value)
            {
                productsInBasket = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public Command<object> DeleteProductCommand
    {
        get { return deleteProductCommand; }
        set { deleteProductCommand = value; }
    }

    public double Sum
    {
        get { return sum; }
        set
        {
            if (sum != value)
            {
                sum = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


Your VM needs to declare that it is implementing INotifyPropertChanged.

@Jason, I have very little experience with MVVM and NET MAUI. Could you explain in more detail how to implement this correctly?

This is basic C#.  To declare that a class implements an interface, use public class ClassName : InterfaceName followed by the rest of the code for the class

Oh, thanks. Initially, I gave your words a completely different meaning

It is safest to recalculate the sum
private void DeleteProduct(object obj)
{   
    var selectedItem_DTOProductAndQuantity = (obj as DTOProductAndQuantity);
    if(selectedItem_DTOProductAndQuantity is null) 
    {
        //You can display error message
        return;
    }

    // Sum -= (obj as DTOProductAndQuantity).product.Cost * (obj as DTOProductAndQuantity).quantityInBusket;
    
    ProductsInBasket.Remove(selectedItem_DTOProductAndQuantity);

    // Recalculate Sum
    Sum = 0;
    foreach (var i in ProductsInBasket)            
        Sum += i.product.Cost * i.quantityInBusket;
        
}

